# How to use two columns in HAVING clause using MAX

Tags: sql, max, having

Is it possible to use two parameters in HAVING clause using MAX ? Or I need to create some variable ?
The problem is that I have two columns: date_id (int) and period_time (time). The task is to filter the table using MAX value in these two columns

When I had one parametr, I used code

SELECT
PlotsID
date_id
period_time
fieldID
FieldName

FROM data_base

WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT        1 AS Expr1
FROM         data_base AS t2
WHERE      PlotsID=data_base.PlotsID
GROUP BY PlotsID
HAVING         (data_base.date_id =MAX(date_id) ))

But I understand, that I need to group and filter this very big table (over 1 mln lines of data) with both date_id and period_time

Comment: Please add sample data and also tag with your database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle).

Comment: Looks like you want a window function here.

Comment: database  -  SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

If the table is not too large you can simply use a subquery in the WHERE clause(test1 is an example table):

```
Select *
from test1
where period_time= ( Select max(period_time) from test1)
```

Comment: Thanks . Table is too big, more than 1 million rows

Comment: And I need both MAX value - Date_ID and period_time

Comment: Select *
from test1
where (period_time= ( Select max(period_time) from test1) OR date_id= ( Select max(date_id) from test1))
-----------------------------
@Dmytro1988
The above one will give you the rows for the maximal date_id and period_time.
If the query will be executed just once or rarely it is okay for 1 million rows according to me.

Comment: The query must be executed very often. Thanks, I try to use your code, but didn't get the result . THere is only part of data in this case